# Angularjs ui bootstrap modal sharing information to same controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have the following modal set up in my `cloud` controller. I'm not giving this modal a specific controller to work off of because the goal is to share it with my cloud controller.

I don't tell the modal that it should be using the cloud controller because then the controller will get run twice, and I do not want this to happen.

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $stateProvider
        .state('cloud', {
            url: '/cloud',
            controller: 'cloud',
            templateUrl: 'pages/templates/cloud.html'
        })
})

.controller('cloud', function($scope, $rootScope, $http, $state, $stateParams, $modal) {

    $scope.toggleModal = function () {
        $scope.renameModal = $modal.open({
            animation: true,
            templateUrl: 'pages/templates/modal.html',
            size: "md",
            scope: $scope
        });
    }

    $scope.submit = function(data) {
        console.log($scope.inputData, data);
    }

})
```

The issue I am trying to solve is with an input box in my modal template. I am trying to submit the text, have it be shared, and hopefully updated to one of my `$scope` variables inside the cloud controller.

Below you can see my **modal.html** where on submit, it runs the `submit()` function in my cloud controller. It run's successfully but the console log returns *undefined* for both `$scope.inputData` and `data`.

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <h3 class="modal-title">title</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <input type="text" id="rename_item" ng-modal="inputData" value="" />     
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn_submit fade" ng-click="submit(inputData)">Rename</button>
</div>
```

Could anyone help me figure out what I am doing wrong or how I can get this data over to my current cloud controller?

Comment: Shouldn't the input attribute be **ng-model** *not* **ng-modal**?

Comment: Also, you could just have: **$scope.submit = function() {console.log($scope.inputData);}** and **ng-click="submit()"**

Comment: @camden_kid Nice catch! but `ng-model` still brings *undefined*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A **BIG** shoutout to camden_kid for catching my mistake of misspelling `ng-model`. I accidentally did *ng-modal*.

Just correcting that spelling didn't fix it though.

I don't know why (maybe someone can help explain), but I had to use an object that was already created to get this to work. Just using a variable that was pre-defined didn't work.

So this is my change in my cloud controller:

```
.controller('cloud', function($scope, $rootScope, $http, $state, $stateParams, $modal) {

    $scope.toggleModal = function () {
        $scope.renameModal = $modal.open({
            animation: true,
            templateUrl: 'pages/templates/modal.html',
            size: "md",
            scope: $scope
        });
    }

    $scope.inputText = {data: ""};
    $scope.submit = function(data) {
        console.log($scope.inputText.data);
    }

})
```

And then I did the following to my html:

```
<input type="text" ng-modal="inputText.data" />
```

Comment: The reason is that the modal has an isolated scope.  You have to use the close method, this will pass a promise that is resolved when a modal is closed.  Check out the demo Plunker in the docs for the modal: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal